# select a record except one

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table in which food menus are stored.

```
fmID    fmMenuName
----    ----------
1       Menu 1
2       Menu 2
3       Menu 3
4       Menu 4
5       Menu 5
```

I'm trying to write a query which select from all records except one.

```
SELECT fmMenuName FROM tblFoodMenu WHERE fmMenuName='Menu 5'
```

I want a query which select `Menue 5` from all records but not from one e.g fmId is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `NOT EQUAL` parameter ...  Which in MySQL is `<>`.

So your original query needs an `AND`, which appends to the list of conditionals, then another conditional of `NOT EQUAL`.  This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT fmMenuName FROM tblFoodMenu WHERE fmMenuName='Menu 5' AND fmID <> '3'
```